# How to replace the characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
ID 

Abc0012
BED0045
cAB0027
....
```

I want to replace all the ID values in the table1 like ABC0012, BED0045, CAB0027.

I want to make all characters as caps

Need Query Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ID = UPPER(ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [UPPER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx) function

```
update table1 set id = upper(id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `upper`:

> SELECT upper(ID) FROM YourTable

or:

> UPDATE YourTable SET ID=upper(ID)

Comment: `uppercase` does not exist in TSQL

Comment: shame on me, I got to check as soon as I pressed ENTER and confirmed that my memory is definitely playing tricks on me... :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change them:

```
UPDATE  
    Table1  
SET  
    ID = UPPER(ID)
```

Could work, this is untested though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET ID = UPPER(ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete script that shows how to use the UPPER() function to achieve this:

```
 declare @mytable table (
     somevalue varchar (20)
 )

 insert into @mytable(
     somevalue
 )

 values (
     'abc123'
 )

 insert into @mytable(
     somevalue
 )

 values (
     'xYz456'
 )

 insert into @mytable(
     somevalue
 )

 values (
     'gjriwe345'
 )

 update @mytable
 set somevalue = upper(somevalue)

 select *
 from @mytable
```